# Authenticating Microsoft Azure quickstart Python web app

Tags: python, azure, authentication

I am following the instructions on [Microsoft Azure Documentation for a Python web app quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-python-webapp). I've gotten most of the way through. I've:

- registered the application
- replaced the client id, secret and tenant id in the app_config.py file
- installed as per requirements.txt

The server executes fine, but when I authenticate with my account details, (the same one I used to register the application), I get an error that says:

*Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft Services' and cannot access the application '#' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Please use a different account.*

Note: I've removed the client ID in the error message above and replaced with a #.

Is there something wrong with my account? I would have thought that the account I registered the application with should exist in the tenant? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you use the example code in the link you provide? Anu changes or the same just instead of the client ID with a #?

Comment: @CharlesXu Hi Charles, yes it's exactly as per the quick start instructions. I think I've worked it out though - it appears that my user account did not have an Azure Active Directory subscription, so it wasn't associated with a tenant? I don't think that really makes sense in my head but I was able to connect once I subscribed my user to AAD and the registered the application.

Comment: If you solve the problem please add an answer to display the solution. And I don't think the subscription is the problem. All the things you do have no relationship with the subscription.